# TouchableOpacity onPress not working when trying to setState to a single object in an object dictionary

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

I'm new to react-native and have tried everything I can think of. I've searched for similar threads everywhere.

I have an object dictionary with 4 objects that I am referencing for use in a row of 4 TouchableOpacity buttons. Each button is referencing a different object in the dictionary and I want `onPress` to set the state to that of the button being pressed. Only one of the four buttons should be able to be selected at any given time and the selected button should show that it is the selected button.

Whenever I press one of the buttons, I get this error:
`setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.`

I'm running my code locally using Expo on my Mac with an iOS simulator.

My TouchableOpacity button row component

FloorLevel.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const floorLevel = {
    Basement: 'Basement',
    Lower: 'Lower',
    Main: 'Main',
    Upper: 'Upper'
}

export class FloorLevel extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            floorLevel: {floorLevel}
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <Text style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Floor Level</Text>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState(floorLevel.Basement)}>
                            <Text style={this.state === floorLevel.Basement ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Basement}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState(floorLevel.Lower)}>
                            <Text style={this.state === 'Lower' ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Lower}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState(floorLevel.Main)}>
                            <Text style={FloorLevel.state === (floorLevel.Main) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Main}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState(floorLevel.Upper)}>
                            <Text style={this.state === (floorLevel.Upper) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Upper}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 5, 
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    btnActive: {
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#2196F3',
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 19,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        color: '#2196F3',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:15,
        padding: 6
    },
    btnInactive: {
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#B5B5B5',
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 19,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        color: '#B5B5B5',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:15,
        padding: 6,

    }
});
```

I'm expecting the state to be set to that of the button I choose, and the chosen button should update from `styles.btnInactive` to `styles.btnActive`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState` function takes an object as argument (your component's state is an object). So change the `<TouchableOpacity>` code to `onPress={() => this.setState({ floorLevel: floorLevel.Upper })}`.

Similarly, you'll want to alter the `<Text>` tags code to have a valid style verification, like so:

`style={this.state.floorLevel === (floorLevel.Upper) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}`

Also, you probably have to change your component's constructor, right now it's initializing `floorLevel` with an object and when you press a button `floorLevel` becomes a String.

Comment: @ChaseSmall you should really take a look at your constructor, it's initializing state in a  problematic way. Check Vinod's answer and maybe initialize your state in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `{ }` from the `setState` and the key-value should look like this in your case:

`this.setState({floorLevel: floorLevel.Lower})`

But I am not 100% sure what you expect, because you initiate the `state.floorLevel` with an `object`, then I guess you change it to a `string`.. not sure..

Comment: I was confused on how to initiate the state of `floorLevel`, and I'm still not exactly sure how I should initiate the state of `floorLevel`. Whether I initiate the state of floorLevel as `this.state = { floorLevel }` or `this.state = { floorLevel: { floorLevel } } ` or `this.state = {  floorLevel: ''  }`, the UI works.

Answer (score 0):

:hattip: to @BrunoEduardo for helping me fix my problem. Here is the new code following his resolution steps.

```
// placeholder file
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const floorLevel = {
    Basement: 'Basement',
    Lower: 'Lower',
    Main: 'Main',
    Upper: 'Upper'
}

export class FloorLevel extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            floorLevel: {floorLevel},
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <Text style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Floor Level</Text>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState({ floorLevel: floorLevel.Basement })}>
                            <Text style={this.state.floorLevel === (floorLevel.Basement) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Basement}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState({floorLevel: floorLevel.Lower})}>
                            <Text style={this.state.floorLevel === (floorLevel.Lower) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Lower}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState({floorLevel: floorLevel.Main})}>
                            <Text style={this.state.floorLevel === (floorLevel.Main) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Main}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity testID='floorLevelSelection' onPress={() => this.setState({ floorLevel: floorLevel.Upper })}>
                            <Text style={this.state.floorLevel === (floorLevel.Upper) ? styles.btnActive : styles.btnInactive}>{floorLevel.Upper}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 5, 
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    btnActive: {
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#2196F3',
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 19,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        color: '#2196F3',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:15,
        padding: 6
    },
    btnInactive: {
        borderWidth:1,
        borderColor:'#B5B5B5',
        height: 30,
        marginTop: 19,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        color: '#B5B5B5',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:15,
        padding: 6,

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts when you define the state, as by your code you are pulling in the whole object in and assigning it the name floorlevel.

If you want to change the state on press and then compare the state value and make changes. below code might help a bit

I initialised the state with a level ( basement) and intend to update the same when onPress() will be called

```
this.state = {
        level: {floorLevel.basement}
    }
```

And change the way you update the state

```
onPress={() => this.setState(level: floorLevel.Lower)
```

Now other piece of code should be fine ( update the reference to the state correctly )

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add your thoughts. While I was able to get it working without making your recommended change, I took your advice and made a change because your suggestion is much cleaner and less confusing.